# laravel post is not working

Tags: php, laravel, post

I'am working on simple laravel project where user have a registration page.For this  I have used two methods register(get method) and postregister(post method).
My code:

```
public function register() {

    return view ( 'auth/register' );
}
public function postregister(Request $req) {

dd("sowmya");
    $user = new User ();
    $user->name = $req->get ( 'username' );
    $user->email = $req->get ( 'email' );
    dd($user);
    $user->password = Hash::make ( $req->get ( 'password' ) );
    $user->remember_token = $req->get ( '_token' );

    $user->save ();

    return redirect ( '/login' );
}
```

Get method is working fine.But after submitting form the post method is not calling.even I tried with printing dd("hii") but not displayed. Can someone help me?

```
           @extends('layout') @section('content')<style>
            <style>
             nav {
               visibility: hidden;
             }
           </style>
         <h3 style="margin-top: 70px;" align="center">Signup Page</h3>

         <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="register is-Responsive"
                    style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)">
           <div id="logo-container"></div>
           <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <form action="/register" id="loginForm" method="post">
                @if (count($errors) > 0)
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li> @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
                @endif {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name='username'
                        placeholder="username" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" type="email" name='email'
                        placeholder="email" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span> <input
                        class="form-control" type="password" name='password'
                        placeholder="password" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span> <input
                        class="form-control" type="password" name='password_confirmation'
                        placeholder="confirm password" />
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label> <input type="checkbox"> I agree to the <a href="#">Terms
                            and Conditions</a>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-def btn-block">Signup</button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

@endsection

Comment: did you sent csrf in your form during post request?

Comment: can you post your HTML code too...

Comment: Route::group ( [
   'middleware' => [
     'web'
   ]
 ], function () {
  Route::get ( '/', 'LoginController@index' );
  Route::get ( '/register', 'LoginController@register' );
  Route::post ( '/register', 'LoginController@postregister' );
  Route::get ( '/dashboard', 'LoginController@dashboard' );
 
 } );     this is my route

Answer (score 0):

In normal case, without middleware,

Routes:

```
Route::post ( '/register', 'LoginController@postregister' );
```

In view:

```
<form action="{{ URL::to('/register') }}" method="post"></form>
```

In LoginController:

```
public function postregister(Request $req) 
{
print_r("Came here");die;
}
```

Change the button tag to input:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-def btn-block"></input>
```

Add this inside your form :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Try this.Good luck.

Comment: thnku ...but i tried with this ...the same code worked before.suddenly it is not working from last 3 days...i dont know what the problem is..

Comment: no ...when i submitted form ..user is not saving in db..as well as credentials are displaying in url  as get method

Comment: Change your button tag to input tag on the registration form.

Comment: hey the post url is correctly coming to the proper function? did u checkd? I think its going as get request. Thats y on the url , the data is showing.

Comment: i have given correct url only..but it taking as a get request..                                                    http://localhost:8000/register?_token=eKlbPKtbYq4Wll3hu0bgQulAyAbZBe7kFmGvCeR7&username=sowmya&email=sowmyaa%40gmail.com&password=ss&password_confirmation=ss                      this is the url iam getting  on form submission.i dont know where the problem

Comment: i have tried your code in my system and perfectly routing to the post controller. I think you better start from the fresh. If you need guiding, then i can give that.

Comment: Route::get('/register',function () {
    return view('ViewName');
});
Route::post('/register','CreateController@register');

Comment: thanks sunil..i have tried same with other system...it worked fine...but i dont know why it is not working in my system..

Comment: is sessions causes any problems to post methods..i want to know the problem with my code